# How do you find e ban numbers in a list of strings and only print the non- e ban numbers? e ban numbers are numbers that contain "e" when spelled

Tags: c

e ban numbers. If a number that contains an e when you read it, then that
number will be banned. Write a C program that will ask for a series of number. Your
program will only print the numbers that are not e ban numbers.
Your input and output will be integers.

Input: 4 44 1001 164 29
Output:4 44

It's my first time encountering with e-ban numbers. What algorithm do we use to determine them?

Comment: Try leaving the numbers as strings and applying `strcspn()`.

Comment: We are talking eban numbers like "sEvEn", "ElEvEn", aren't we? Is "nin(e)", i.e. with a silent "e" an eban number? The silent "e" in "onE" and "ninE" seems to be relevant, judging from the desired output.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think you miss the point. I think it is about "onE", not about anything which can be seen in a string of digits.

Comment: How would you do it without computer? What is relevant? -> check spelling for each digit. Also check if you have digits for "hundreds"

Comment: Assuming Yunnosch is right, you should be way more precise about what you want to achieve. Without Yunnosch's comment it would be completely unclear how you want to get an `e` in a number. I first thought you got "IBAN" wrong... ;)

Comment: @Gerhardh I agree. My comment should not be part of the needed clarify for the question. Voting to close for lack of details. Though I suspect I accidentally might habe solved OPs problem. In that case, if OP edits "Please help me with guessing at the idea of eban numbers in this assignment." I would be open to turn my comment in to an answer, if OP consider it one.

Comment: uhm, the input are integers so I cannot search the string for a letter e. Unless there is a function that can turn integer into letters?

Comment: You can first turn them into written numbers (instead of digits) then search that written representation. I guess that was one of your previous assignments. Or something similar. Otherwise I propose to create a focused question on "How to turn e.g. 44 into 'fourty-four'?" But read [ask] for this and for that question.

Comment: You need to make a simple mapping of a digit to the corresponding word. You can also just skip the strings for the word and directly map to "has an e in it". Don't expect to get a function for everything. Most of the time it's you who writes that function

Comment: @Yunnosch `if(strcspn(numstr, "0135789") < strlen(numstr))`

Comment: Is `200` an e-ban number?

Comment: What language are we using here for the numbers? In English, neither "six" nor "two" have an "e" in them, so why are they banned from the example given?

Comment: @WeatherVane Very interesting, but what about 400 "four hundrEd"?

Comment: @AdrianMole because the number containing the 6 also contains 1.

Comment: @AdrianMole onE hundrEd sixty four and twEnty ninE?

Comment: Ah, OK. I thought you were just testing each digit.

Comment: @Yunnosch "four hundred" and "four zero zero" both contain **e**.

Comment: @WeatherVane Even more interesting. Your proposal works better than I managed to follow.... Though I tend to read "four oh oh".

Comment: If the whole number is written as an English sentence, then every number contains "hundred" except those with 0 in the 100's digit. So every number is eban unless it had a > 0 in the 100's digit.

Comment: You need to update the question with information about what it means to “read” a number. In particular, state whether “246” is “two four six” or “two hundred and forty six” or something else, and state whether “204” is “two oh four” or “two zero four” or something else and whether “30” is “thirty” or “three zero” or something else.

Answer (score 2):

The question is unclear what is meant by "reading the number". If it means that

```
164
```

is

> one six four

then the function `strcspn` can be used to check out the number as a string – whether it contains the "e-ban" digits 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9.

Comment: how do i make it so that whenever theres a match you ignore it

Comment: Perhaps [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72711687/how-do-you-find-e-ban-numbers-in-a-list-of-strings-and-only-print-the-non-e-ban/72712257?noredirect=1#comment128435487_72711687).

Answer (score 1):

Turn the integer input, e.g.

- 44 into string representation like "fourty-four"
- 1001 into "one thousand and one"

There are question on StackOverflow on how to do that step.
Then use a string searching function to look for "e".

This is intentionally not giving the full solution in code, matching [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)